# connect React + Flask to an RDS MySQL db

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-rds

Here is the code for the project:
https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-firefly-x9vl6

I have a project, with a Flask backend serving a React frontend. On AWS, in RDS, I have created a MySQL database. I would like to be able to connect the Flask to the database in RDS via SQLAlchemy. This is the application structure:

[image]

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help, you need to import create_engine, scoped_session, you also need to export DATABASE_URL i.e, in ubuntu/mac use export, for windows use set run code in terminal

```
export/set DATABASE_URL = the url of database
```

for connecting to database, use below

```
# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Comment: where in my code should i put these? in my main.py?

Comment: in the application.py, the set up database, and export thing in terminal before running flask